Error: AADSTS700054: response_type 'id_token' is not enabled for the application
I receive this problem when trying to authenticate myself into my webapp on Google Chrome. It does the same for the mobile versions too.
Firstly, Microsoft Edge works perfectly. However, Google Chrome displays the following message:
*Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
AADSTS700054: response_type 'id_token' is not enabled for the application.*
I have ID Tokens on and had Access tokens on (but turned them off as they never made a difference).
I also have this code in my program.cs:
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
        policyBuilder =>
        {
            policyBuilder.WithOrigins("https://envisioncrm.azurewebsites.net/")
                         .AllowAnyHeader()
                         .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

I have looked at previous stackoverflow threads and I have already made the changes that have been listed.
I cannot seem to come right.

Update: It works on my Edge Browser, but not other employees testing it.

You have to enable Access Tokens and ID tokens in Authentication blade and try and that makes difference

Hi there. They are already enabled.

Then can you trying clearing the cache and check as it must in other browsers too

I received the same error:
AADSTS700054: response_type 'id_token' is not enabled for the application.
I cleared the cache in both browsers and tried to login.

I fixed the issue.
I had to add CORS redirect URIs to my azure app service, and adjust my code to include:
.AllowCredentials();

